# Favourite questions

Tags: support, questions, bookmarks

I marked few interesting questions as favourite ones. I expected that I can see list of these questions somewhere. But I was not able to find where (I looked e.g. on my personal page and there is nothing).

**Could you please tell me where I can find list of my favourite questions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this - the first is to append `?tab=favorites` to you main profile page to give e.g. `https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/23/mithrandir24601?tab=favorites` for mine, `https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/9006/martin-vesely?tab=favorites` for yours or `https://[sitename][.meta].stackexchange.com/users/[usernumber]/[username]?tab=favorites` in general.

Alternatively, to navigate there manually using the mouse, from the activity (/main/front page) of your profile, go to the second 'block' of tabs from the top and the 6th tab from the left is your favourites.

In pictures, that is:

Clicking on your profile near the top right of the screen:
[image]

Leads you to this page:

[image]

(Note that the 'activity' tab, circled in red has been selected.)

Then click the favourites tab, about a quarter of the way down, in the (horizontal) middle:

[image]